# Static import in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, import, static, intellij-idea

Is there a way to easily import the following builder() method in eclipse?

```
public class SomeClass {

    public static class SomeClassBuilder {
         public static SomeClassBuilder builder() { ... }

         public SomeClass build() { ... }
    }

    public static void someMethod() { ... }
}

SomeClass someClass = SomeClass.SomeClassBuilder.builder().build();
SomeClass.someMethod();
```

With IntelliJ you just have to move the cursor on builder() and use the static import shortcut in order to add builder() to the list of static imports.
Eclipse seems to be able to static import someMethod() but not builder().

On my windows machine I have to select "SomeClass.SomeClassBuilder.builder()", mouse right click, 'y' (copy qualified name), ctrl-v, position the cursor on builder() and ctrl-shift-m: a lot of work.

Is there any other way to do that? Any plugin maybe?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

That doesn´t work and I don´t know a way to make it happen, but what could make your life a little easier is to add `SomeClassBuilder` to the Content Assist Favoriters in the Preference menu "Java -> Editor -> Content Assist -> Favorites". After that your `builder()` method appears on the content assist. (And the content assist adds the static import for `builder()`)

Comment: Forgot to mention that I have hundreds of those builders in my project, and adding them one by one to the favourites is less than ideal :)